How do i configure the vercel.json app to allow routes like /api/items
i am trying to configure my vercel.json file so that when i visit my backend app hosted in vercel, i am able to see the routes working properly.
However, when i do this, the only route working is the / route and i can see the message, but the api/...routes are not working. I have been trying to host my backend app to vercel for hours now and everytime i seem to be through one problem another on appears.
This app works as expected in localhost, i have never hosted a backend app in vercel before thats why i am having problems.
    {
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],

    "headers": [
        {
            "source": "/api/(.*)",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                    "value": "https://to-my-frontend"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "value": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "value": "Content-Type, Authorization"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Here is my index.js:
    const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const connectDb = require('./config/connectToDb');

const app = express();

// Enable CORS for the specified origin
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://to-frontend-app',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Import routes
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoute');
const itemRoutes = require('./routes/itemsRoute');

// Use routes
app.use('/api', userRoutes);
app.use('/api', itemRoutes);

// Connect to database
connectDb();

// Default response for root
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the API' });
});

// Export the Express app as a module
module.exports = app;

Someone help

I recently faced the same issue when deploying nodejs to Vercel, The key is to properly configure the routes section in your vercel.json.
The main thing that fixed my API was adding the routes configuration. and This tells Vercel how to handle different URL and for more info please check out my github nodejs swagger template its a open repo and you can check how I have deployed and it is deployed on vercel :)
The first route handles all paths starting with /api/
and with this changes it should worked:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.js"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.js"
    }
  ],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value": "https://to-my-frontend"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "Content-Type, Authorization"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


,If i use this approach i get an error that, i cant use routes and headers at the same time

can you please check this file and the routes I have added here? and try? Nodejs
